# Run-Time Check Failure #0 C++

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc, egl

The project I am running uses CodeJock - ToolKitPro (MFC) to provide a user interface and uses other libraries to do some pretty intensive rendering in some of the windows.

We are rendering with the PVRVFrame libraries (OpenGL).

When I hit the first OpenGL function call - it happens to be `eglGetDisplay`, but any function call from these libs seems to cause the same error - I get the following error message:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention.

I have read that this is a problem where the function was declared with a certain calling convention (__stdcall in this case) but called with a different convention - however I'm not sure how that could be possible.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code

Comment: What can I show you that would help?
I figure this is not so much a code problem as it is a project setup / library configuration problem, but I'm happy to post some code if it would help.

Comment: If you're using `GetProcAddress` the code that obtains the function pointer would be nice. The code calling the functions would also be nice. Knowing how the calls are made and how the calls are declared is helpful in these kinds of situations.

Answer (score 2):

Okay sorry, this is embarrassing but I solved it after a couple days bashing my head against the wall.

Basically I was linking to the wrong libEGL.dll and libGLESv2.dll.

I had my project setup to look in my project's local library directory, but I had older versions of these libs in my system directory: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\

Depends.exe was telling me to look in C:\Windows and C:\Windows\system32 but I'm guessing I had some paths setup to look in the SysWOW64 folder so that threw me off for a while too.

Thank you Captain Oblivious for your interest and your help.

Comment: Thanks - I had the same problem. No idea what those files were doing in that folder, was a relatively fresh PC.